# Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services:0.0.+

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I am using Android Studio to create an Android app. Its a very simple app and am trying to integrate Google+ sign in into it. So, I am following Google's documentation provided at https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#next_steps
The above documentation is provided from Eclipse's point of view..but I am using Android Studio..so I am stuck at 'Step 2: Configure your Eclipse project'. I added google play services library into my project but could not add 'Android Private Libraries'. Now if I clean my project, I am getting the following error:

```
    Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
       > Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services:0.0.+.
         Required by:
             EarlyBirdAppManagerv1:app:unspecified
```

Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have install with SDK Manager Google Play Services ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is you haven't specified a version of the Play Services library for it to look for: There's no 0.0.

The best solution is to undo whatever changes you've made to try to integrate the library and go to Project Structure > your module > Dependencies > Library dependency. If you've already installed the Google Repository through the SDK manager, it should offer you a dependency for Play Services in that dialog with the right version number filled out.

Comment: for me was most helpful sentence **If you've already installed the Google Repository....**